# $n$-bouquet is semi-locally simply connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

How to give a proof of the statement above? Just choosing a point $x_0\in B_n$ with $B_n$ the $n$-bouquet (this is a collection of $n$ circles only identified in one point). Thus I have to find an open set which contains $x_0$ and is simply connected. I think the difficulty lies in the point where all circles come together, because all other open sets only contain a piece of a line and are thus simply connected. Some ideas to solve this???

Thank you :)

Comment: at that point, the $n$-bouquet just looks like $n$ lines crossing, which is a contractible space. you can make this as formal as you like

Comment: Oh yes thats true :D is this question really so simple?! :D

Answer (score 0):

Hint: can you show that the subset $X=S^1\setminus\{-1\}\subset\mathbb{C}$ of the circle is contractible? How about $X \sqcup X/\sim$ where $\sim$ identifies the points $1$ in both circles? Can you generalise this?